# mod rewrite friendly url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to regular expressions and need to rewrite an example URL:

```
http://domain.com/quiz.php?id=1
```

To the friendly URL,which looks like forum URL, like this:

```
http://domain.com/1-quiz-title
```

So `1` is the GET variable. Title must be lowercase only

I tried the following but it seems incorrect:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ quiz.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It's picking the GET variable as `1-quiz-title` while it should be only `1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the get variable is only numbers, you want the regex to be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)- quiz.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So the regex matches some amount of numbers first and groups it (the parentheses), the matches a "-". Note that there isn't a `$` for end of match, this is essentially going to ignore the title completely, not even going to try to match it. The title doesn't need to be in the rewritten URL so we don't really care what comes after the `-`.

Comment: The number is the unique identifier of the quiz while the letters are the title of the quiz with spaces replaced with hyphens. For example, a quiz title "How Long Will You Live?" with id "1" in database, should have URL "http://domain.com/1-how-long-will-you-live". Hope it's more clear now

Comment: what about that the title must be only lowercase letters and hyphens? after the id

Comment: @MichaelSamuel are there other URL's that start with numbers? The title itself isn't used in the rewrite.